# Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.vue-templates'

Tags: docker, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn Docker. I installed Docker ToolBox on Windows 10 (I have Home Edition, so I can't use regular Docker installation because that Windows version doesn't have Hyper-v).

I tried [this container from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/ebiven/vue-cli/) to use with the Vue.js framework:

`docker pull ebiven/vue-cli`

I added new alias as was written on container page (I changed name to vuejs because I have vue installed locally):

`alias vuejs='docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":"$PWD" -w "$PWD"  -u "$(id -u)" ebiven/vue-cli vue'`

And then in the console I wrote:

`vuejs init webpack .`

I got an error message:

`vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.vue-templates'`

How to fix this?

Comment: It works on my linux machine so I can't help you. Just two questions : where do you put your alias? And Does `id -u` works on windows?

Comment: @D.Gonçalves, yes, it works.

Comment: And where do you put your alias? On the windows host or on the virtual machine that runs Docker?

Comment: At Windows host.

Comment: ok so your probleme is probably that you don't use the same user id on windows and on the virtual machine that run Docker. I don't know how docker machine works so I can't help you but that's something to get started.

Comment: I solved this problem. That ```-u "$(id -u)"``` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, I realized that I need to remove that part of the command: `-u "$(id -u)"`. Now it works properly.

So, it should be:
`alias vuejs='docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":"$PWD" -w "$PWD" ebiven/vue-cli vue'`